# Query to group table data by one column and sum the product of two other columns

Tags: php, sql, group-by, sum, grouping

The following code displays the ordered products individual weight:

```
$weightsql = 'select op.products_name,
                     op.products_quantity,
                     p.products_weight 
              from ' . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . ' op
              left join ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p on op.products_id = p.products_id
              where op.products_id =  ' . $pro['products_id'];
        
$weightq = tep_db_query( $weightsql );
        
while ($weight = tep_db_fetch_array( $weightq )) {
    if ($category_parent_id != 0) 
        $list_items[] = $weight['products_weight'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

This shows the wieght for each of the products ordered. What I am stuck on is instead of showing seperate weights, I need to show a total weight. For example, if the product was ordered three times, and it weighs 7kg, the code at the moment is showing:

```
Product  7.00  7.00  7.00
```

How would I make it show the total weight, 21kg?

Comment: In this case, you can't stream your data. You have to iterate over all data before being able to sum them all up.

Comment: Let's see, I have an **array** and I want the **sum** of the items in it. Now, what might such a function be called...

Comment: @DaveRandom - lets just put him out of his misery..... [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_sum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

```
array_sum() examples
<?php
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";

$b = array("a" => 1.2, "b" => 2.3, "c" => 3.4);
echo "sum(b) = " . array_sum($b) . "\n";
?>
The above example will output:
sum(a) = 20
sum(b) = 6.9
```

Comment: I've tried that, why else would I ask the question? Im getting an error, on the result

Comment: @user1879415 Might it be because your array contains `strings` instead of `integers` or `floats`?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a counter to 0 before the loop and add do it during the loop, like this:

```
 $total = 0;
 $weightsql = 'select op.products_name, op.products_quantity , p.products_weight from ' . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . ' op left join ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p on op.products_id = p.products_id where op.products_id =  '.$pro['products_id'];

 $weightq = tep_db_query( $weightsql );

 while ($weight = tep_db_fetch_array( $weightq )){
      if($category_parent_id != 0) {
           $list_items[] = $weight['products_weight'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
           $total += $weight['products_weight'];
      }

 }
```

The variable $total should then return 21.

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected the product by its id, the easiest solution is to multiply the number of rows by the weight. No need to put it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$weightsql = 'SELECT op.products_name, SUM(op.products_quantity * p.products_weight) AS weightsum
              FROM ' . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . ' op
              LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p on op.products_id = p.products_id
              WHERE op.products_id =  ' . $pro['products_id'];

echo $weight['weightsum'];
```